# Angular Validation Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

[image]

[image]

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasError')
    at template (user-profile.component.html:18:41)
```

I can try so many thinks but ı cant fix that problems pls help me

Comment: please include code directly, not an image

Comment: Could you share the code of this file user-profile.component.html with line numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hasError property on a Form Control.  That's the issue.  The property you are looking for is called errors.  Check out https://angular.io/guide/form-validation.